# What is the recommended way to import react classes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components

I've observed a way we import and extending in react. The way I usually write is as following.

```
import React from 'react';

class SomeClass extends React.Component {
    //Some code
}
```

but I've seen people using the following way as well.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

class SomeClass extends Component {
    //Some code
}
```

What is the best way or the best practice when writing the imports. is it the 1st way or the 2nd way? or is there any other way as the best practice. Please advice.

Comment: Approach 2 is much cleaner. I have seen much-experienced developers use and recommend that approach.

Comment: Well, the correct way would be the one that is followed in your project.This is an opinionated question. There will be people preferring either one of the approach. So its better to decide in team and come with the coding style to be followed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no best practice for this particular case. Both snippets do exactly the same thing. As @Rajesh said, it's only a matter of opinion and personal preference.

*Personally,* I prefer approach 1 because we have already imported `React` which is where `Component` is under. Also, I think `extends React.Component` vs `extends Component` makes little difference to the eye.

That being said, if you are exporting *multiple* React components from the same file, it makes more sense to use approach 2, as that would shorten your code a bit.

Answer (score 0):

One example where case two is useful is say you have a module that exports multiple hard-coded constants or helper functions

Such as

types.js:

```
export const ACTION_1 = "...";
export const ACTION_2 = "...";
```

From an understanding point of view, it's pleasing to a developer to see in other file:

```
import {
 ACTION_1,
 ACTION_2
} from './types.js'
```

At the end of the day, it's syntactic preference.